# Enable CORS configuration in Payara for OpenAPI specification

Tags: swagger, openapi, connection-timeout, payara-micro

I am currently trying to  enable CORS for the OpenAPI specification in my Payara Micro server.

I'm working with Payara Micro 5.2021.9.

I have a microservice running on 10.0.2.15:8080 inside a Vagrant image that I want to access the OpenAPI specification through Swagger-UI (version 4.1.3) on my host machine at localhost:8080, but I keep getting a "Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue" from the Swagger-UI page when I try to bring it up.

Most resources I found say simply to add the following Payara configuration to enable OpenAPI CORS Headers be added. It is even documented here by Payara: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/microprofile/openapi.html

I added this configuration and it does add the headers, but I still keep getting the "Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue" from the Swagger-UI page. Reading further up on Swagger-UI it specifies the header should look like this: (Detailed here: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/cors/)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, api_key, Authorization
```

When I do a manual curl for my openapi endpoint the headers show the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
```

The noticeable difference is the "api-key" header is missing which I think may be required by Swagger-UI. This issue affects both accessing Swagger-UI in a virtual machine via Vagrant and also when these services are deployed in Docker containers. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make Payara and Swagger-UI play nicely with each other when dealing with cross-origin specific REST calls? Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: When you see "Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue" in Swagger UI, what's the full error message on the Console tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Helen The error I get is the following:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

The full error I see on the webpage from Swagger is the following:
`Fetch error
Failed to fetch http://10.0.2.15:8080/openapi
Fetch error
Possible cross-origin (CORS) issue? The URL origin (http://10.0.2.15:8080) does not match the page (http://localhost:8080). Check the server returns the correct 'Access-Control-Allow-*' headers.`